# AnyArray.map() is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Hi everyone i'm just starting with reactjs and following a tutorial, the teacher wants to pass an array of cities and then use map() function to convert a string to component i followed his steps but a i don't know why react returns to me cities.map is not a function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import LocationList from './components/LocationList';

const cities = [
  'Granada,es',
  'Moscu,ru',
  'Washington dc,us',
  'Barcelona,es',
  'Madrid,es',
 ];

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <LocationList>cities={cities}</LocationList>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is where i create the array with some cities and call to LocationList with this array.

```
import React from 'react';
import WeatherLocation from './WeatherLocation';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const strToComponent = cities => (
    cities.map(city => (<WeatherLocation city = {city} />))
);
const LocationList = ({cities}) => (
    <div>
        {strToComponent({cities})}
    </div>
);

LocationList.propTypes = {
    cities: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}
export default LocationList;
```

Where react says to me the error is in strToComponent function telling me that cities.map is not a function. Do you know guys why is happening that? I would appreciate your help

Thanks very much guys.

Comment: instead of making it another function, can't you directly use that in jsx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two of problems here.

You are not passing `cities` your `LocationList` component here, you are passing it as a child. Hence change this:

```
<LocationList cities={cities} />
```

Second problem is you are passing `cities` to your `strToComponent` component wrong:

```
const LocationList = ({cities}) => (
    <div>
        {strToComponent({cities})}
    </div>
);
```

Here, you are passing it as an object, but actually it is not. Change like that:

```
const LocationList = ({cities}) => (
    <div>
        {strToComponent( cities )}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was really usefull, i could solve it. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You could solve it or you solved it :) In either case, glad that you did it. Just accept one of the answers if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `cities` as a prop to `LocationList`, not as `children`.

```
<LocationList cities={cities} />
```

`strToComponent({cities})` is equivalent to `strToComponent({cities : cities})`, which is not what you want. Just pass in the `cities` array as argument instead.

```
const LocationList = ({cities}) => (
    <div>
        {strToComponent(cities)}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was really usefull, i could solve it. I really appreciate your help.